# How to include plain files and folders into Eclipse product/plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a plugin, which is using some plain text and binary files when running.

This is because plugin is using some third-party code, which works as in conventional application, i.e. taking data from within application directory.

When I was running plugin from within Eclipse, these data was just laying inside project directory in some folders.

To access this data I was using code like

```
    public static final String CorePropertiesPath = "conf/core.xml";
    public static URL CorePropertiesURL;

      //...

        Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(ID);
        CorePropertiesURL = bundle.getEntry(CorePropertiesPath);
        try {
            CorePropertiesURL = FileLocator.resolve(CorePropertiesURL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I.e. to access data from file in "core/core.xml" in my project's directory, I was first converting it with `getEntry()` method and then with `resolve()` method.

This was working.

But when started to create products, I found that my files like "core/core.xml" just absent in target directory. Probably they should reside in my bundle jar, but they are not there.

How to force them to come in prescribed place?

Comment: Have you included these directories in the `build.properties` file - if they are not listed there they are not included in the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Check build.properties file (you can edit it on the 'Build' tab of a manifest editor). Add

```
Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
```

in your MANIFEST.MF if you want to generate a directory and not a jar for your bundle.